# Remote MQ Server Authentication

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to figure out how we would configure / setup the authentication, Queues, and Queue managers for connecting an MQ Client that is on a server / domain completely separate from the MQ Server it will be forwarding messages to.

I would assume that in a normally organizational environment you could just use Active Directory (if hosted on windows servers) for the authentication / AD lookup.  However, in this scenario because they are different orgs you couldn't do that?

Can you simply apply SSL certs to both client / server and use that as your authentication? If so is that just applied to the Channel used in the connections?

Not sure how to proceed forward with this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Hardening WebSphere MQ](http://t-rob.net/links) presentation for v7.0 and earlier.  The thing to remember is that WMQ does not authenticate anything.  It authorizes based on OS identities and groups but there is no password checking being done.

For situations where QMgrs and clients live on Windows networks, the connection uses the SID and so it appears that some useful authentication was performed.  BUT if a connection from a non-Windows platform is attempted, the Windows QMgr uses the string representation of the ID.  So for example, if someone has a Linux VM on their desktop they can easily create a user ID called MUSR_MQADMIN and the Windows QMgr will accept the connection.  There is a setting that causes the Windows QMgr to only accept connections with SIDS that it can resolve but even there its just a matter of knowing what the SID values are to spoof them on a connection.

The lesson here is that **any** QMgr, even one on Windows, must be configured to authenticate remote connections.  With WMQ v7.1 and later, the QMgr has functionality to map X.509 certificate DNs to user IDs, or to perform IP filtering.  Prior to v7.1 these functions required an exit such as [BlockIP2](http://mrmq.dk).  Capitalware sells [MQAUSX](http://www.capitalware.biz/mqausx_overview.html) which has the functions of BlockIP2, plus will perform ID and password authentication and is supported.

The first recommendation is to use a v7.1 QMgr so that you get the `CHLAUTH` rules for mapping and filtering.  Even if you don't use certificates v7.1 limits administrative connections so it is harder for an attacker to gain full admin rights.  Then if you need password validation, use SSL channels (to encrypt the password and prevent simply replay attacks) in combination with an exit that you can write yourself or purchase.

Just be aware that allowing a connection from outside your domain doesn't present any new challenges.  The pre-v7.1 Windows QMgr that does not have MCAUSER set in the channel definition or by an exit allows remote administrative access, even from connections originating in the local Windows domain.  There was *always* a need to harden that QMgr, even though honest users will have received authorization errors if the administrator did not set up auths for them.

**Summary:**
For clients originating outside your administrative domain, I'd recommend mutually authenticated TLS/SSL channels.  The same page I linked to above also contains the WMQ Security Lab guide and scripts which show how to script the creation and exchange of WMQ certs and configure WMQ Explorer with them.

Whatever else you do, the `MCAUSER` on any legitimate channel must be set either in the configuration or by an exit.  If the client is allowed to specify the ID, there is nothing to prevent it from specifying an administrative ID.  For channels that are NOT being used such as `SYSTEM.DEF.*` and `SYSTEM.AUTO.*`, set the MCAUSER to a value that cannot be a local ID such as `no!body` or on v7.1 and later `*NOACCESS`.

Comment: As always your responses are priceless.  Thanks T.Rob.  I will create a new SO request if I have further questions....S